# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce at kafka.utils.TestUtils.tempDir(TestUtils.scala)

Tags: scala, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

While using `@EmbeddedKafka(topics = { "checkins" })`
I am getting an error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce
    at kafka.utils.TestUtils.tempDir(TestUtils.scala)
    at org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaBroker$EmbeddedZookeeper.<init>(EmbeddedKafkaBroker.java:738)
    at org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaBroker.afterPropertiesSet(EmbeddedKafkaBroker.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1790)
```

I am using **spring boot 2.3.3.RELEASE**

My gradle looks like

```
            compile("io.confluent:kafka-json-serializer:$confluentJsonVersion")
            compile ("org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients: $kafkaVersion")
            implementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")
            implementation("org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafak:$springKafkaVersion")
            implementation "org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:$kafkaVersion"

        testImplementation("org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test:$springKafkaVersion")
        testImplementation("org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.13:$kafkaVersion")
        testImplementation("org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.13:$kafkaVersion:test")
        testImplementation ("org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:$kafkaVersion:test")
```

Comment: Note: You shouldn't need `kafka-clients` as a test dependency if it is already mentioned as a compiled one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That interface only exists in the `kafka_2.12` jars.

It appears you somehow have a 2.12 `...-test` jar and a `2.13` kafka jar (which is not what your gradle says).

What does `gradle dependencies` say?

Comment: You are correct there was 2.13 scala included by *group: 'io.findify', name: 's3mock_2.13*
I had to downgrade it and it worked.